# Contacts deleted in Sales Cloud are not deleted in Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect, sales-cloud

We have to be missing something simple, but when we delete a contact in Sales Cloud, shouldn't that contact be automatically removed from Marketing Cloud?  We tried a bunch of options including many iterations of changing our query in automation studio to try to filter out deleted contacts.  We thought maybe using the isDeleted flag in our where statement, but that wasn't it.  What are we missing?  Contacts deleted in Sales Cloud need to be deleted and removed from journeys automatically in Marketing Cloud.

Comment: Did you try to delete the contact by API based on a trigger after delete in Sales Cloud ? https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/DeleteByContactKeys.htm

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think it works that way. If you are using synchronized data extensions and you delete a contact, they will be removed there, but once they are in journeys or all subscribers, removing them from Sales Cloud will not remove them from Marketing Cloud...

Answer (score 1):

Deleting a contact in SFDC will not automatically trigger a delete of the Contact in SFMC. Although there has been great progress in integrating these tools, such core concepts are still split.
Deleting a contact in SFDC should remove the contact from the Synchronized Data Extension, which means that you can cannot rely on the isDeleted flag to be set as the entire record would likely be gone.

Generally, I would say you have three basic options

1. Run a query to calculate which contacts are in your All
   Subscribers (and MobileConnect Demographics and MobilePush
   Demographics if you use those) compare with who is in your Contact
   synchronized data extension. Then once every week/month you run a
   manual delete request ->
   https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_cab_delete_contact.htm&type=5
2. Create a SSJS activity which triggers a delete using Contact Key or List (as calculated in 1) once per hour/day/etc to the API -> https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/restrict-contact-key.htm
3. Trigger the above mentioned API as part of an onDelete trigger in SFDC (I would usually go with this one)